# cannot find Trash folder! Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, find, delete, trash

I am running a preinstalled version
of ubuntu 18.04 but cannot find Trash folder.
The typical places don't have the folder.

```
~/.local/share/Trash <-- does not exist
 /root/..../Trash <-- does not exit
```

The directory should most likely be here but it's not

```
 /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash  <---does not exist
```

Hmm ... so I ran a search as follows:

```
sudo find / -type d -iname Trash
```

The output was not nice:

```
find: ‘/run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied
/home/$USER/.local/share/evolution/..../trash
/home/$USER/.cache/evolution/.../trash
/user/share/doc/HTML/.../trash
```

and that's it!
By

```
...
```

I meant there are various directories ending with /trash. But that's useless to mention anyhow since we are not really finding the TRASH can.

(Note that I do see a Trash bin on my Desktop, which is ironic. And yes it is empty.)

Question is, where is my TRASH FOLDER ? 
And why do I receive the following output when I run the find command

```
find: ‘/run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Try to delete some file, and see if they appear when you click on the Trash icon on desktop.

Comment: I already did ffrom the Download folder .... and not sure where they end up. How to best trace them ? Grep ? or Find ?
I don't see the deleted item in the desktop "Trash bin" ...

Comment: Adding now: I did the following "sudo find / -type d -iname deletedfile" and got as output find: ‘/run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied

Comment: Use `type -f` instead of `type -d`, and then tell us.

Comment: Just did and I get the same output as above.

Comment: I did install some more trash related utilities; and using "type -f" for finding "trash" helps to show them. For instance, I found "/usr/bin/trash" ... but that's not a folder that's the program to delete specific files using "trash [file]"

Answer (score 4):

The trash folder in your home directory is generated once a file from the same device that your home directory is stored on gets moved to the trash. In case you're deleting a file from another device, e.g. a different hard drive or USB stick, Ubuntu will use the (insert mountpoint)/Trash-(insert uid) directory. This is specified in [FreeDesktop.org Trash Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open terminal either via <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> shortcut key, or by searching for 'terminal' from app launcher.
2. Run command to create and edit an empty file called `trash.sh`:

   ```
   gedit ~/Documents/trash.sh
   ```

   When the file opens, paste following lines and save it.

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    icon=$HOME/.local/share/applications/trash.desktop

    while getopts "red" opt; do
      case $opt in
        r)
      if [ "$(gio list trash://)" ]; then
        echo -e '[Desktop Entry]\nType=Application\nName=Trash\nComment=Trash\nIcon=user-trash-full\nExec=nautilus trash://\nCategories=Utility;\nActions=trash;\n\n[Desktop Action trash]\nName=Empty Trash\nExec='$HOME/Documents/trash.sh -e'\n' > $icon
      fi
      ;;
        e)
      gio trash --empty && echo -e '[Desktop Entry]\nType=Application\nName=Trash\nComment=Trash\nIcon=user-trash\nExec=nautilus trash://\nCategories=Utility;\nActions=trash;\n\n[Desktop Action trash]\nName=Empty Trash\nExec='$HOME/Documents/trash.sh -e'\n' > $icon
      ;;
        d)
      while sleep 5; do ($HOME/Documents/trash.sh -r &) ; done
      ;;
      esac
    done
   ```
3. Make the script file executable and run it via the 2 commands:

   ```
    my-machine:~$chmod +x ~/Documents/trash.sh
    my-machine:~./Documents/trash.sh -e
   ```
4. Search for 'trash' in software launcher and select **Add to Favorites** in its context menu.
5. Finally open **Startup Applications**, click **Add** to add a new startup app. In the modal in the **Name** field add `trash icon` and in the **Command** field add `/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/Documents/trash.sh -d`
6. Reboot Ubuntu, and the trash can icon will change when it’s empty or not empty.

Reference: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/add-trash-icon-dock-launcher-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score -1):

When trying to remove Trash's files, instead of doing:

```
rm -r /home/*/.local/share/Trash/files
```

I have done:

```
rm -r /home/*/.local/share/Trash
```

Then, the trash file disappeared when running:

```
ls /home/*/.local/share/Trash
```

As a result of that, I have done:

```
nano /home/*/Desktop/file
```

Then I have used the nautilus file manager in order to remove it by press on it and hit supr.

Finally, when I have done:

```
ls /home/*/.local/share/Trash/files
```

The created file was there !!

Comment: Please be extremely careful anytime you are running `rm -r /home/*/...`
I presume that your intention is to do this for all users, perhaps as a cron job, but if so this should be pointed out very explicitly... Saying just do `rm -r /home/*/anything` is asking for trouble...

Easy for a new user to read that without really understanding it and do some major self inflicted damage...

Also, note that Linux doesn't really have a "Trash" folder quite the same was as Windows or Mac's do. Different apps, like in your case nautilus, may create a Trash folder on the device that your moving files from,

Comment: @erwin I did not use /home/*/ , it just was a way to use any user (my user, your user, his user, her user... whatever) but thanks anyway !!